# Passport Expiry for my kids less than a month and travelling Home country

Tags: transit, passports

My Kids Passport Expires in April 1st week and planning to travel to my home country through Doha airport .
Visa: Permanent Resident 
Travelling from Usa to India
Transit : Doha Airport

Will there be any issue on-boarding in Doha airport ?
Pls Advice.

Comment: When are you planning to travel?

Comment: Im planning by March end .

Comment: Why would you have a problem boarding in Doha? The problem I would be worried about us being allowed to transit in Doha.

Answer (score 2):

No one will stop you from boarding for your own country with a *currently valid* passport, even if it expires tomorrow. If you might need a transit visa in Doha that can be a problem but no, boarding for India will not be a problem.

Usually if you remain airside and catch your connecting flight within 12 hours you do not require a transit visa in Doha at all

Comment: Hanky Panky, are you an Indian citizen?

Comment: Nope, i'm not. That's why i mentioned last paragraph might not be relevant